Issue in PowerPoint / Power BI plugin - Embed Power Bi report can't show preloaded objects
i have integrated various Power BI graphics that show live data into a PowerPoint report using the URL. The graphics with the live data were automatically reloaded, after the respective slide was clicked on. If the slides were not clicked and the entire report was exported as a PDF instead, the graphics that were loaded the last time were displayed.
You can also see it in the preview on slide 3: the objects shown there were loaded the last time.

For some reason, for the last two weeks, when the graphics have been reloaded and the PowerPoint report has been saved and reopened, the preview no longer shows the last loaded graphics, but blue hexagons. The blue hexagons only disappear when I click on the slide and the graphics have been automatically reloaded. If I don't do this step, i.e. click through each individual slide but click on PDF export straight away, the PDF export shows the blue hexagons again. The problem is, however, that due to time constraints, I can't always click on each individual slide, but only on a few slides, and the rest of the slides including the graphics they contain should remain unchanged.

After the issue came up, i updated Power BI and PowePoint with the latest versions, but it didnt help. Also using Power BI service is not a option as the report consists of over 200 pages and rebuilding it would take too much time.
How can I restore the old status and ensure, that the last loaded graphics are shown instead of the blue hexagons?
Thanks for any help!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
